# Implement Basic Authentication with Jersey on Client and Server

Tags: java, jax-rs, basic-authentication, jersey-2.0, jersey-client

I have implemented a REST server with JAX-RS that provides some endpoints which consume x-www-form-urlencoded data and respond with XML.

I have two clients: an HTML page in a browser and a Java client that uses the Jersey 2 client API to send a request.

So far, everythings works fine. Now, things start to get tricky as I try to implement basic authentication on server and client. My first approach was to use servlet authentication which works fine. I have added users and roles in tomcat-users.xml and enabled basic authentication in my server's web.xml.

The problem is that I have to implement application level authentication in a javax.servlet.Filter for this exercise. So, basically the filter shall intercept any request to the server and check the Base64 decoded 'Authorization' header content against a HashMap that contains valid user credentials and respond with a 401 status code if no match is found.

Surprisingly, that works. *But only as long as I keep the servlet authentication running*. As soon as I deactivate the servlet level authentication my application level authentication doesn't work anymore. I have checked that my filter is not ignored by adding entries to the Hashmap that are not contained in the tomcat-users.xml and vice versa. Only requests with credentials that pass both the servlet authentication as well as my own make it to the server.

Debugging revealed that all requests miss the Authorization header as soon as I turn off servlet authentication. My guess is that servlet authentication somehow compensates for a mistake I made and "repairs" my requests but I can't see how.

Here's the relevant client code:

```
HttpAuthenticationFeature httpAuthenticationFeature =
        HttpAuthenticationFeature
        .basic("ceo", "123456");

ClientConfig clientConfig = new ClientConfig();
clientConfig.register(httpAuthenticationFeature);
javax.ws.rs.client.Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient(clientConfig);

webTarget = client.target("http://" + hostname + ":" + port)
        .property(HttpAuthenticationFeature.HTTP_AUTHENTICATION_BASIC_USERNAME, "ceo")
        .property(HttpAuthenticationFeature.HTTP_AUTHENTICATION_BASIC_PASSWORD, "123456")
        .path("RESTService");

Form form = new Form();
form.param("field1", value1);
form.param("field2", value2);

String response = webTarget.path("rest").path("service").path("endpoint")
        .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
        .post(Entity.entity(form, MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_TYPE), String.class);
```

And here's the server code:

```
@Priority(Priorities.AUTHENTICATION)
public class AuthenticationFilter implements javax.servlet.Filter {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {

        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest)request;
        String authCredentials = req.getHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION);

        // authenticate() returns true if credentials are valid
        if (authenticate(authCredentials))      
            chain.doFilter(request, response);

        // should return proper 401 response, but apparently does not
        // as browser shows no prompt for credentials
        else if (response instanceof HttpServletResponse) {
            HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;
            httpServletResponse.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
        }
    }

    // ...
}
```

Thanks in advance!